# Can an enderman place blocks while in a boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In newer versions, enderman can’t despawn while holding blocks as to not slowly delete blocks from the world, and I want to prevent an enderman from despawning. I don’t have any name tags and won’t get any for a while as I’m only beginning my trading hall.

If I keep one in a boat, will it be unable to place a block it’s holding (and by virtue of that, be unable to despawn)?

Comment: as far as I remember, any mob in a boat won't despawn (regardless if it's holding a block)